# best way to use https with development server of Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

what is the best way to use https with the development server of Google App Engine?

I'm trying to develop REST services in Java that will be served over https.
Unfortunately I'm unable to use https while developing locally: 
the development server is always started on port 8888 with http.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use localtunnel to generate and expose your computer as https. See detail here https://localtunnel.github.io/www/ . It works pretty well for me.

Comment: thanks. it looks interesting, but I don't need to have a url that is publicly available. I just want to be able to use it locally for my development.